# Set background image in xmonad

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xmonad

I have just switched from Fluxbox to giving xmonad a go, and I am definitely liking it. However, the one thing I haven't managed to do is to change my desktop background.

I am using Ubuntu 8 (uh, can't remember the value after the point), and I installed xmonad through the package manager, and then ran xmonad from the list of environments available on the login screen.

I have tried setting it using gconftool as suggested on the Haskell wiki, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Regarding prior comment from grawity, the correct syntax is actually

```
xloadimage -onroot -fullscreen <path.to.image>
```

The advantages over xloadiamge on xpmroot are:

- allows png images
- on Ubuntu, has its own package, rather than bein contained in the larger fvwm package

(sorry if this would be better as a comment on previous answer: I can't add comments)

Comment: I'm new to Haskell and Xmonad, and not exactly sure how to use that command in my Xmonad config. How am I supposed to use `xloadimage`?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04, didn't fill if the image aspect ratio wasn't the same as my monitor's.

Comment: @E-rich, put it in your `.xinitrc` file, usually before a line alike `exec /bin/xmonad`.

Answer (score 22):

I had some trouble with `xloadimage` (didn't work at all) and `xpmroot` (only accepts xpms and gimp wrote a strange one that it barfed on), but `feh --bg-fill` worked wonderfully (thanks to some guys on the [arch forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1056875#p1056875)).

Answer (score 4):

Does this command work: `xpmroot ~/background.xpm &`? Where `background.xpm` is the filename of the image you want to be your background.

Comment: Btw, I am not sure if that stays as your background after logging out. You might need to add that command to your ~/.xsessions or ~/.xinitrc

Comment: For image formats other than XPM, `xloadimage -root $path`

Answer (score 0):

I use [feh](https://feh.finalrewind.org/) for this:

```
feh --bg-fill ~/pictures/background
```

This lives in my ~/.xprofile and also produces a script ~/.fehbg which may be run to set the same background and configuration later. There are alternative arguments that may be used aside from `--bg-fill`, `man feh` elaborates.

Feh is widely available and may be installed from the default Ubuntu and Arch linux package repositories, and likely others.

Answer (score 0):

For me putting

`xsetroot -solid Indigo`

in `~/.bash_profile` is sufficent.

Using [`xsetroot`](https://sites.ualberta.ca/dept/chemeng/AIX-43/share/man/info/C/a_doc_lib/cmds/aixcmds6/xsetroot.htm) does not require installing (and possibly compiling) a separate program (I don't see feh, xloadimage or xpmroot packages on Red Hat distributions).  This program also supports bitmaps with configurable foreground/background colors to allow non-solid backgrounds.